# Usage of "until" and meaning of "I didn't notice that until you told me" when I realized something after someone told me

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning

> I didn't notice that until you told me.

What I  would like to say is that I didn't notice something for some time. Then, someone told me. Then, I realized. I'm not sure if the previous sentence is correct and have the same meaning. I'm not sure also  if it's the  proper way to use "Until". Would you help me, please?

Comment: @user3169 sometimes I make grammatically correct sentences but it turns out they aren't correct like "I went to shop" instead of "I went shopping". The second one is correct of course. That's why looking "until" in a dictionary would not be that helpful for me.

Comment: Clarification: "I went to shop" isn't incorrect. It just doesn't mean the same thing as "I went shopping." If you were asked why you went somewhere, "I went to shop" would mean that the reason you went was to shop. If you were asked what you did today, "I went shopping" would mean that what you did today was shopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is written the way people usually write or say it. From your description, I believe it correctly expresses your intent.

Comment: Sometimes I make grammatically correct sentences but it turns out they aren't correct like "I went to shop" instead of "I went shopping". The second one is correct of course. That's why looking "until" in a dictionary would not be that helpful for me

Comment: Please focus on answering the question at hand. Also, in general, "yes, this is correct/no, this is incorrect" type answers are not very helpful. Please try to explain why the usage of "until" is correct in order to address OP's (and future readers') concern.